# cascading drop down menu from database

Tags: database, drop-down-menu, binding, jqgrid

when I hardcode values it binds the list and everything works, but as soon as I populate it from a database it doesn't accept the list(I think it's not binding). And, when I console log the lists both they show the same object as well. Does anyone know what might be wrong?

[Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5mCD.png)

[Jqgrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5qML.png)

[HardCode(working)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jix2D.png)

[HardCodeDisplay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsxFV.png)

[DatabaseCode(not working)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCDVa.png)

[DatabaseCodeDisplay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEf5W.png)

Answer (score 0):

The resolution of your problem is to use **dataUrl** editoptions parameter (maybe in combination with **buildSelect** )
The documentation of Guriddo jqGrid describes these options [here:](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/editing/#editoptions)

I have prepared a example which can [be found here](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/functionality/dataurl/)